# how to host name and IP address of the instances deployment from the deployment manager for a particular deployment session?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-deployment-manager

how to hostname and  IP address of the instances deployment from the deployment manager for a particular deployment session?

I have seen it can be done via gcloud but I am looking for alternate via saving files through jinja

Also, would like to know if we can save via Jinja templates

need to know if there are any postscript available for gcloud deployment manager

for example, I have deployed 4 centos instances and now I need to create a config file using the above four instances and then go about starting services on all four.

I doubt it can be done through start-up script

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a creation of a vm instance reserving the desired IP, specifying the hostname and the start-up script where you start the services of your machines, then, check the REST file at the bottom of the page to see the actual labels used for that and where those should be used, but remember that for IP static assign you must reserve one or more first, for internals check [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address), for externals check [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address).

Comment: I really like it to be dynamic, looking for a way to find the host name and IP address dynamically and have this file across all the instances use it as an input to my config template

Comment: I am thinking of a solution to find hostname and ip address using startup script and append it to file on a share directory

Comment: Well for shared files you could store one in a bucket inside cloud storage.

Comment: Also, you could run the command gcloud compute instances list and append the output to that file

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance-templates based on this documentation[[1]](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/create-a-configuration) and deploying your VM/s with gcloud[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/deploy-your-resources). The Hostname and IP Address can be specified on the instance template itself:

> gcloud deployment-manager deployments create [DEPLOYMENT_NAME]
>   --config [CONFIG.YAML]

I am not familiar with Jinja but based on Google doc [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/create-a-template#writing_jinja2_or_python_templates), you can use it to create templates used by Deployment Manager.

You can also add a metadata resource in the template to use the startup-script[[4]](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/setting-metadata-and-startup-scripts). Keep in mind that startup-script can simply download and execute a python/bash if it is come to be too complex.

Comment: You can look at these simple to base your own configuration file https://github.com/Aahzymandius/deployment-manager/tree/master/GCE-instance

IP addresses can be specified in the network section as natIP (External IP) or networkIP (Private IP)